# Can I force the browser to use CSS @font-face instead of font installed on system?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Do browsers ignore `@font-face` if they determine that a  CSS-imported font is already installed on the client OS?

I have a number of uncommon fonts installed on my system for design, etc.  It would appear that browsers render these fonts with slight differences, depending on whether or not they are installed on the client OS.  My guess is that the browser ignores the CSS font import if it determines that the font is already installed on the client OS.

The problem with this is that these rendering distinctions, however slight, can affect spacing, positioning and alignments, causing me to see a different version of a page than visitors.  I have to uninstall the font (a pain to do every time) or preview it in a virtual machine (less of a pain, but still a pain).

Is there any way I can tell CSS, **"only use this specific font from the CSS import and *ignore* the font installed on the client OS?**"

**EDIT :** This seems to resolve the issue:

1. Ensure the CSS `@font-face` specification uses a **different** string for `font-family` than what is installed on the system.
2. When referencing the font elsewhere in CSS, use:

   `font-family: System Installed Font Name, 'Imported Font Name', Fallback Font;`

Comment: my experience is that if you define `@font-face` then call it lower in the css file (`body { font-family: 'myfontname' }`) then it will ignore everything installed on the client's OS and will take your font installed on the server...

Comment: try using other name than font real name to describe your font in css. I think it would fool the browser and let you achieve what you want.

Comment: @ShirinAbdolahi: that's exactly what I've done, which is why this is all the more strange.

Comment: Please add this info to your question.

Comment: Is your question answered or do you need more help?

Comment: @MarcusRommel: it appears to be resolved, thanks!

Comment: Then can you mark it as answered so everybody can see that your problem is solved. And if given answers don't fit answer it by yourself and mark it.

Comment: @MarcusRommel: will do, sorry about that.

Comment: Related: you can make Firefox ignore user-installed fonts on your computer ("client OS"). For details, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76903494/1334619) to the question "Disable installed fonts from system in browser".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*From the edit in my question:*

This seems to resolve the issue:

1. Ensure the CSS `@font-face` specification uses a **different** string for `font-family` than what is installed on the system.
2. When referencing the font elsewhere in CSS, use:

   `font-family: System Installed Font Name, 'Imported Font Name', Fallback Font;`

Comment: This is a great workaround... i had a similar issue where i forgot to include the font-face but because it was installed on my system, I didn't realise it wasn't rendering on other browsers until after launch. Is there anyway to rename Google fonts?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you take in account font variations (bold, italic).

I solved it this way:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "DejaVuMono";
  src: url("styles/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic, oblique;
}   
@font-face {
  font-family: "DejaVuMono";
  src: url("styles/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf");
  font-style: italic, oblique;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "DejaVuMono";
  src: url("styles/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf");
  font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: "DejaVuMono";
  src: url("styles/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
}
```