# Chrome use local font instead of site font

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I use font-face and web font on my own website:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'example';
  src: url('example.eot') format('eot'),  
       url('example.woff') format('woff'),  
       url('example.ttf') format('truetype'); 
}
```

If client has the font installed with the same name, client font is loaded instead of web font.
Is there any solution to load the web font instead of the local font?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to use the local font or do you want to force a remote font?

Comment: I want to force a remote font

Comment: Thank you for editing your question, it is now clear what you want to do.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25959365/can-i-force-the-browser-to-use-css-font-face-instead-of-font-installed-on-syste

Answer (score 0):

Check if your font is in same lacation as the page, cause if its not on the same location you should use `src: url('../example.ttf');` You should src only for TIF, not multiple, I don't know if its corect. TIF is suported by all browsers.

Comment: This font really is in other location, font name and and it's location just is a sample.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp